# Get manager details for a set of user from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Problem:
Get manager details for a **set** of user.

Solutions tried so far:

**Trial 1**:  Tried to get managers for user one by one. This won't work for mainly two reasons

1. It can get [throttled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling) by Microsoft.
2. It will take too long to process

**Trial 2:**  Tried Batch Request but it has [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#json-batching) that it supports only 20 request at a time

**Trial 3:**  Tried Graph api filtering and expanding using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=id in 
('id1','id2')&$expand=manager&$select=id,displayName,mail
```

The problem is that it's not possible to do select on manager. It returns all the data in manager. So if there is many user then the response will be too big.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=id in 
('id1','id2')&$expand=manager($select=id,displayName)&$select=id,displayName,mail
```

For v1.0, if there is select in manager then it gives `Bad request`. For beta, even though the select presents it returns all the manager data.

Any more solution?

Comment: When you deal to retrieve good amount of data from Graph API then you will endup hit the throttling - its by design for any cloud architecture. Instead of grabbing all at a once or when you use complex query like you do above, you need to use pagination - the best practice in such scenario. I know there might be a limit, but its to safeguard that the service/API call is not abused. Also v1.0 doesn't provide the ability, but beta endpoint does that for you.

Comment: I agree with dev.

Comment: I agree, pagination could be a solution. My usecase is generating a report and even for the smallest duration, there could be a lot of users (approx 500–1000). One solution could be - do a batch request in every second. Then it will take much longer to process.